# Password Recovery in Modal or New Page

Tags: usability, accessibility, password-recovery

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a **popup** password recovery vs a **new page**?

Comment: I doubt you'll find any reasons specific to password recovery.

Comment: It would be better to provide some specific examples or a use case where the requirements from a business, technical or user point of view can be discussed and weighed up so it is not subject to opinions and preferences. I think it is a valid question but perhaps needs to be more focused for a better discussion and to get answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in the style of your product.

If you introduced popups in your product, you can go with popups, if not then try to avoid popups.

Advantages are in the favor of style.

Disadvantages: If you are using third-party add-ons as a handler for modals/pop-ups, this can cause you bad UX in terms of loading these modals/pop-ups.

EDIT: If your interactions are right, once again, it's all about style.